# Can anyone identify this gyro?

Tags: gyro

Can anyone identify this gyro?

It's from the guts of a (deceased) hovering toy and I'd like to find a datasheet.

[alt text http://www.hodgepig.org/gyro.png](http://www.hodgepig.org/gyro.png)

Comment: Votes to close are coming in. Likely because there is no picture or other information displayed. Are you using a broken link to a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the part number nor the logos are familiar to me, and I'm assuming that you've already done the usual Google searches, tried to narrow it down by package size/pin count/axis count on distributor sites, and looked for the repair manual and replacement parts lists.  If no one here recognizes it, the next (and possibly last) step is to try to contact the remnants of the manufacturer.

What kind of info are you looking for?  If it's analog (Plugged into ADC pins or buffers), you should be able to reconstruct what you need just by soldering on some test leads, powering it up, and waving it around. If it's over a digital interface, I wish you all the best of luck in deciphering the init sequence, command set, and data format.

That said, unless you're trying to upgrade your hover toy, **I think your needs will be better served by purchasing a new one with a known manufacturer, datasheet, and distributors.**  It's perfectly reasonable to pull off sturdy, easily identifiable parts (switches/buttons, potentiometers, LEDs, and connectors are generally the first things I reach for) but I would generally just leave unknown ICs, ESD/age sensitive, or highly variable parts where they sit.

Comment: It's definitely analogue. I'm hoping to reuse it in a prototype to save some money. I'll see if I can power up the board and measure the output.

Comment: @Joby: Most of the STMicro gyroscopes can be had for under $10.  Save yourself the time and effort, and just buy a new one. IMO, prototypes should be as similar to the final product as possible.